# How can I make Content Items without a CommonPart appear in the content list?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I created a custom Type that has a `UserPart` attached to it.

According to [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/2192) you can't add a `CommonPart` to content that also has a `UserPart` because it causes a `StackOverflowException` but I would still like items of my custom Type to show up in the content list. I already store CreatedUtc and PublishedUtc in the custom PartRecord, can I manually plug these in somewhere?

EDIT: For clarification, my specific scenario is that I am building a public facing Orchard website based on existing data that was used in a private application up to this point. I have a legacy table with user accounts that need to be mapped to Orchard Users but they also represent travel agencies that visitors should be able to browse and that Orchard admins should easily be able to edit and create through the Dashboard. I got the idea to create a TravelAgency type with a UserPart from [Sipke's webshop tutorial](http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content Types do not require to have a CommonPart to show in the Content List. If i remember properly its done by triggering the Creatable() in your migrations. 
Also if you have a UserPart, you could Lazy loaded or just reference it via Foreign Key.

Why would you like something like that to be part of the Content List? I usually keep my business-specific Content Types tucked away in a nice section, so there are easier to visualise and use for users.

There is definitely a bug but as they comment you could extend taxonomies to accomplish your task and keep in mind sometimes changing the Orchard Codebase might fit your purposes, you only have to keep track of your changes when you upgrade next time. I have done it a couple of occasions to fit my projects.

If i remember properly, its been a while.. If you look in the core code where the Content List is created it looks for Creatable() Types. digging even more inside the code, chances are the Query in charge will join the CommonPart, hence your problem. You could easily add another query in the controller and add whatever you are after. The problem though, will be refactoring the rest of actions to accommodate your your type too. Way easier isolating your new Type. had to look at it for you, check this baby: Orchard.Core.Contents.Controllers.AdminController

Comment: Well, the Content Type is both creatable and listable but it doesn't show up in the Content List as long as I don't attach a CommonPart to them and  re-publish them. When I remove the CommonPart the items disappear from the list again. In my case the type isn't business-specific. It's both a user and something that visitors can interact with on the front-end.

Comment: I think that is where your problem lies, ultimately. If you could explain a bit better your scenario, perhaps we could find a workaround.

Comment: My specific scenario is that I am building a public facing Orchard website based on existing data that was used in a private application up to this point. I have a legacy table with user accounts that need to be mapped to Orchard Users but they also represent travel agencies that visitors should be able to browse and that admins should be able to easily edit and create through the Dashboard. I got the idea to create a TravelAgency type with a UserPart from [Sipke's webshop tutorial](http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-8)

Comment: I can see you have commented in the article. It seems like you are trying to do this in a very quick manner.  
First: Users are users, can not be Travel Agencies. A User can be the owner of a Travel Agency and you should be able to restrict editing with Permissions. Second: Customers, Travel Agencies should not be in the Content List,  IMHO as they are not Content. You can abstract functionality quickly from a List implementation to achieve what you are trying to do and keep everything organise and tucked away nicely.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747276/orchard-cms-extending-users-with-fields-exposing-values-in-blog-post

Comment: I guess you are right. What you propose is a better and more correct way to achieve what I want and is probably how I will move on, so I'm upvoting this. That being said, I would still like an answer to my original question: "Is it possible to include items of a Type without a CommonPart in the Contents List?" I will not use this now but I still want to know for future reference and for anyone who ends up here through Google.

Comment: If i remember properly, its been a while.. If you look in the core code where the Content List is created it looks for Creatable() Types. digging even more inside the code, chances are the Query in charge will join the CommonPart,  hence your problem. You could easily add another query in the controller and add whatever you are after. The problem though, will be refactoring the rest of actions to accommodate your your type too. Way easier isolating your new Type. had to look at it for you,   check this baby:  Orchard.Core.Contents.Controllers.AdminController

Comment: Orchard has been my choice of CMS for a while. You learn lots by just looking at code written already. Documentation is getting better but still always look at the Core code to learn how stuff is done and how you can accomplish things. sometimes i download new modules, only to see how they do things or get inspiration. you never know, if there is a better way to do something... actually you do. there is always a better way...

Comment: Thank you for your extensive help! Perhaps you can add your comment about Contents/AdminController to your answer for completion's sake. I'll go ahead and accept it.